# Flex Node sockets connectivity

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sockets

I am working on a Flex app using Node.JS on server side and utilizing sockets to feed my clients.
The issue is: My application works fine when I launch it from Flashbuilder, it can connect to server and feed data to my clients. But when I try to access this app using url, it doesn't work.

A quickie,
Working link:
D:\Dev\workspace\MyProj\bin-debug\index.html

Not working link: (swf loads, but no data)
http: //ip-address:3000/flexapp/index.html

Looks like some security issue. But I am not sure as my mind refuses to yield a solution.
Any help is much appreciated.

**Further exploration:**
I tried many suggestions given over the web as follows:
First, to my understanding, Socket.io itself provides you with flashpolicyfileserver at port 10843 and still I am having issues as mentioned above.
Secondly, I tried running the flashpolicyserver as explained [here](http://forrst.com/posts/node_js_Flash_Socket_Policy_Server-9vS) using authbind, but still unable to resolve my issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I looked/searched all that before posting this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am answering my own question.
The setup that I am using is Flex4.6, Node.JS with Socket.IO, [FlashSocket API](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO)

When I faced this issue, I started correctly by specifying crossdomain.xml for my app. But that didn't worked. Then I tried using a seperate policy server at port 843, even that didn't worked. But all through this, I found that socket has been initialized and disconnected at a later point. So I ended up with Flashsocket causing this issue. I took the source code for that and debugged. I found that policy URL is being generated based on the ip+host provided to it. It's a good approach, but it simply doesn't provided any way to customize this policy URL.
What I did was just modified in such a way that I can pass my own policyURL and whenever it is passed, Flashsocket should use that otherwise, it continue to do the policyURL in old fashion. And it worked.

My little changes to FlashSocket:

```
....
private var policyURL:String;
public function FlashSocket( domain:String, protocol:String=null, proxyHost:String = null, proxyPort:int = 0, headers:String = null, policyURL:String = null)
{
....
this.policyURL = policyURL;
....
}

protected function loadDefaultPolicyFile(wsUrl:String):void {
            var policyUrl:String = "xmlsocket://" + URLUtil.getServerName(wsUrl) + ":843";
            log("policy file: " + policyUrl);
            if(policyURL){
                Security.loadPolicyFile(policyURL);
            }else}
                Security.loadPolicyFile(policyUrl);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I guess..that is what I am doing. This function was pointing to a more restricted location, where as I modified it in a way where you can provide a URL to your global policy file. Thanks.